# Topology equals the the collection of all unions of elements in a basis

Tags: general-topology

Topology equals the the collection of all unions of elements in a basis

Is there a difference between "collection of all unions of elements" and "all unions of elements"

I am kind of confused by term "collection"

Comment: Is exactly the same. The point is that a topology generated by one basis is defined as the set formed taking unions of basis elements. It means, take all possible unions, then each of that possible union form what we will call as open set...

Comment: Does that mean that single element also belongs to the topology

Comment: Absolutely! Stay calm, its questions are natural